# General Setting Allow Multiple Email Notification

Tags: email, options, notifications

WordPress Version: WordPress 3.2.1

Settings -> General
http://www.example.org/wp-admin/options-general.php

I would like to have multiple email address in the Email Address textbox.

I tried abc@abc.com, xyz@xyz.com, after I save it. It become abc@abc.comxyz@xyz.com

How can I allow multiple email on that field?

We need this function because we have multiple admin in the website.

Comment: Add you other admins as separate users and give them admin permissions? In WordPress each user has one primary email address.

Comment: As far as i know its not possible and there are a few tickets open on the track for this issue

Comment: Other Admin did not get any notification, only the email address entered in the General Settings is received.

Comment: @Bainternet May I know where is the ticket, I can go there vote for it.

Comment: @Shiro i think its http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/10726

Answer (score 3):

It's not really a WP-specific solution, but if you set up a Gmail address (and likely others), you could create a filter to automatically forward notifications generated by WordPress to other admins.

Short of WordPress adding multi-email notifications, that might be **a workaround** to temporarily solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

To add multiple admin emails in your wordpress site, it is possible by modifying wp_options table in database.

1. Go to phpmyadmin using cpanel credentials
2. Find wp_options table (if you set table prefix 'wp_' on the time of wordpress installation)
3. find admin_email entry in 'options' table
4. Edit the 'optiona_value' against 'admin_email'
5. type as much email you want using comma and space like admin1@gmail.com, admin2@gmail.com, admin3@gmail.com
6. do not put comma at the end of last email
7. save it

Answer (score -1):

I had an instance where I needed to send multiple emails any time a new user registered as there were a few different processes that needed to happen to onboard a new user. I accomplished this by adding a custom options page and custom fields to hold the email addresses so they could be easily changed, then hooking to the user_register event and gathering those emails to also send out the new user's information. This functionality could easily be extended or developed as a plugin to handle other email notifications as well. You could even pull email addresses directly from your Users info based on their account permissions or roles depending on how you need this functionality to work.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/user_register

If you don't want to write the PHP for it, you can easily create custom options pages with custom fields using plugin ACF with the Option Page addon. http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/

My first instinct was to just edit the PHP in /wp-includes/pluggable.php which is where the emails are actually fired, however I suggest against this as any upgrade to the WordPress core will overwrite your modifications.

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Comment: It's a more valid answer than setting up email forwarding filters in Gmail. At least it gives the OP a different method to accomplish his goal within WP.

Comment: I already downvoted that one. Anyway, the question really is about how to filter and change that. There are [plugins](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/10726) linked on one of the according track tickets, you could filter the sanitization of [`update_option()`](http://queryposts.com/function/update_option/) and alter [`is_email()`](http://queryposts.com/function/is_email/) with one time filter or the return value of [`get_option()`](http://queryposts.com/function/get_option/). That would be something that could be the base for an answer...